# Apache / httpd default configuation from docker image

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have this output when run Apache, using:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
```

the stdio is:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Apr 30 23:08:14.602222 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140596800061504] AH00489: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 30 23:08:14.602371 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 140596800061504] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

How can I hit the apache server locally then with a browser?

Here is the default config that I see in:

```
 /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/27ec1911066ab4de85305dfa14bb7165

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the container came up and Apache is running, so you should be able to point a browser at localhost or 127.0.0.1, which should display the default page ("It Worked!" or something similar).

Since you're running the docker container, also make sure you have port 80 exposed in the Dockerfile and that no OS firewall settings are getting in the way.

Edit: if that warning message bothers you (it bothers me), you can just add a directive like `ServerName localhost` to the httpd.conf to fix it.